# Getting same response multiple time from web service

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, chat, nsxmlparser

I am making a private chat application, in which I am getting some problem like -

1.Some times I am received last chat multiple time.
 2.Some times the long data like a large image, not come proper.

I am calling the web service in every 5 sec through this code -

```
NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:
                 [self methodSignatureForSelector: @selector(getNewMessages)]];
       [invocation setTarget:self];
        [invocation setSelector:@selector(getNewMessages)];
        timer1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 invocation:invocation repeats:YES];
```

So I want to ask that what is the proper way to call the web service after received the full data. I am using NSXMLParser to getting the data.

Answer (score 2):

There are two way to handle this -

1) You can call another request when you receive complete data of your first request, in below method

```
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveData:(NSData *) data
```

2) When you finish with the parsing, then you can trigger your another request -

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,
I have tried both of these option and getting these problem -
1) In first case when data is too long then after the approx half data  received it again call web service.
2) In second case this method is call again and again, and due to this my local database table entry is insert multiple time.

Comment: You should check the last element tag of your xml for second solution.

Answer (score 0):

please look [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project) which gives you a idea to choose the best xml parser in objective-c.

Try to use the TBXML parser because it is very faster to parse the xml than NSXML parser which may solves your problem.